# Windows 7 multitouch capabilities with HTML5

Tags: windows-7, cordova, multi-touch, sencha-touch

I have a problem: There are HTML5/CSS3 mobile frameworks on the market like Sencha Touch and Phonegap which can use the multi-touch gestures of the iPad/iPhone, Android, etc.

That's working fine, I can test it. But now I need to know what's about Multi-Touch displays based on a Windows 7 OS. Are there also multi-touch capable in a webkit-based webbrowser like Safari or Google Chrome?
On a normal PC with mouse / keyboard I can do tap, double-tap, etc. but of course no pinch (zoom a picture with two fingers). Is this possible on a Win7 multi-touch display?
Does anyone know that or can test it? There is a demo:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/
-> Events
Doing a two-finger zoom there must be a "pinch" output. On the iPad, there is one, on the normal PC, I can not get it. But it is only possible on a Safari, Chrome, perhaps FireFox 4 webbrowser, because IE8 FireFox 3 does not support HTML5/CSS3 very much.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 4 supports multi-touch, see [here](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/08/firefox4-beta3/).  However, the Sencha-touch only really supports webkit browsers, and doesn't  work with firefox so you might have to try the [Starlight browser](http://starlight-webkit.org/Starlight/), however it is so old (well over a year!) that it might not work with Sencha either...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So with Safari or Google Chrome I can use a Sencha Touch frontend on mobile devices, normal PCs with mouse/keyboard and with a MT display with Windows 7 I can do two-finger gestures in the safari webbrowser? Okay, and if I want to enable Firefox as well, I have to write some more source code with MozTouchDown, ... but this is not standard, so I think I won't use them...